# Holder inequality for 3 functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, holder-inequality

Suppose $f \in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$, $g \in L^2(\Omega)$, and $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is bounded domain. Is the following a correct application for Holder inequality?

$$ \int_{\Omega} f^2 \cdot 
 g  dx = \int_{\Omega} f \cdot f \cdot 
 g  dx \leq \|f\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)} \|f\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)} \|g\|_{L^1(\Omega)}$$

Using the fact that $L^2 \subset L^1$ in bounded domains.

Comment: in the particular case its just $\int f^2 g \le \sup(f^2) \int |g|$

Comment: Why is $\sup(f^2) \geq \int_{\Omega} f^2$? Can't the integral be greater than the supremum?

Comment: Where did I say or use $\sup(f^2) ≥ \int_\Omega f^2$? I just used that pointwise in $x$, $f^2(x) g(x) \le |g(x)|\sup_{y\in \Omega} f(y)^2.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you can recursively apply the Hölder inequality using associativity to get
$$\|f^2g\|_{L^1(\Omega)}=\|f\cdot (fg)\|_{L^1(\Omega)}\leq \|f\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}\cdot \|fg\|_{L^1(\Omega)}\leq \|f\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}\cdot \|f\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}\cdot \|g\|_{L^1(\Omega)}$$